# Animate Font Awesome Chevron icon rotation on collapse/expand

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I want my icon to rotate visibly when the collapsible content is being hidden or is showing up.

Here's my function that adds a chevron icon and rotates it:

```
$('[data-toggle="collapse"]').each(function(){
    var collapser = $(this);
    // TODO: 'collapsed' class should be added manually if the toggled element is not shown
    // i.e., if you remove 'show' class, add 'collapsed' class, or this function is confused
    collapser.append('<span style="float:right;"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right'
            +(collapser.hasClass('collapsed')?'':' fa-rotate-90')
            +'"/></span>');
    collapser.on('click', function(){
        var chevron = collapser.find('.fa-chevron-right'); // it was replaced with svg
        if (collapser.hasClass('collapsed')) {
            chevron.addClass('fa-rotate-90');
        } else {
            chevron.removeClass('fa-rotate-90');
        }            
    });
});
```

I'd like to add smoother transition, but better without css, by modifying this code only. CSS is tooo confusing for me

Any other critique of this code is welcomed

Answer (score 3):

To make your animations smoother you can make use of the css `transition` property.

Simply add this code to your css:

```
.fa-chevron-right {
  -webkit-transition: transform .4s; /* Safari */
  transition: transform .4s;
}
```

or you can add the CSS directly with `jQuery` by modifying your code `appending element` this (not recommendet):

```
 collapser.append('<span style="float:right;"><i style="transition: transform .4s;" class="fa fa-chevron-right'
    +(collapser.hasClass('collapsed')?'':' fa-rotate-90')
    +'"/></span>');
```

You can learn more about CSS `transitions` here:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

In general, I recommend you to learn `CSS` and create your animations whenever possible with it. You will see it's much easier and you get ways better performance.

Comment: sorry, that didn't change anything. I created the css file and I see in Crome debugger that the style was applied. Still, it just changes without transition. May be it is because I am adding a class (`fa-rotate-90`) rather then modifying some property, so that the browser can't see how it can transform one representation to another?
In other words, probably I have to modify `transform: rotate(90deg);` instead of adding that F.A. class?

Comment: Your css worked perfectly for me. HTML: <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>. JQuery: <my target element>.toggleClass("fa-rotate-180");  CSS (taken from answer above):  .fa-chevron-down {
    -webkit-transition: transform .4s; /* Safari */
    transition: transform .4s;
  }   Font Aweson version:  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.2/css/all.css">